# Vue on drag one player name , drags the whole list

Tags: vue.js, vuedraggable

I am using `vue-draggable` and trying to drag player name. It contains two draggabale list where it can drag items from one to another.

From the **first list** when I drag items, it drags only one player name and **that's correct**.

But when I drag items from **second list**, it drags as a whole group. If the second list contains two player name as San and Kim. When I drag Kim , it drags San at the same time. Is there a way to make this second list `teamByTime2` to drag only one name at one time, like as first list `dataList3`?

I have uploaded array objects on `JSFiddle` code as well. This is how my array looks for first and second item list.

[image: First List = datalist3]
[image: Second List = teamByTime2]

Below is my code on `JSFiddle`

https://jsfiddle.net/ujjumaki/78vsbu3q/26/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the list arrays need to have the same model.
Said otherwise, dataList3 and Reservation_people need to contain the same kind of objects.

If it's not the same as what you receive from the API then you'll have to transform the data model after fetching and before saving.

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-ptolemy-1yg9w?file=/src/App.vue:1227-1245